# passing an element after changing outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, outerhtml

I want to change some element's outerHTML and then pass it to a function, so that the function can do something with it:

```js
const bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for (let i = bars.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
  const bar = bars[i];
  bar.outerHTML = `<h1 class="bar">${bar.innerHTML}</h1>`;
  const foo = new Foo(bar);
  // ... some code
  foo.doFoo();
}

function Foo (bar) {
  this.bar = bar;
  this.doFoo = function() {
    this.bar.innerHTML = `Foo${this.bar.innerHTML}`;
    console.log('doFoo:', this.bar.innerHTML);
    // expected on page: "Dog" --> "FooDog", "Turtle" --> "FooTurtle". This doesn't happen.
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="bar">Dog</p>
<p>Cat</p>
<p class="bar">Turtle</p>
```

However, while the DOM changes after outerHTML changed, the variable `bar` is still referencing the "old" (unchanged) version of the element, which of course doesn't exist in the DOM anymore. Therefore it is not possible to change the DOM content anymore.

Explanation of this behavior on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes):

> While the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose
>   outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the original
>   element

How can I achieve that the Foo-Object still knows the correct element in the DOM, without having to query the DOM again?

Comment: Check if this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613977/how-to-get-reference-to-the-new-dom-object-after-changing-content-with-outerhtml. I would close as duplicate but I don't want to dupe hammer this yet.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to grab a reference to the `nextElementSibling` element of each one whose `outerHTML` you are going to change. Let's call that one `next`.

Then, once you update the `outerHTML`, you get an updated reference to the new element with:

```
next.previousElementSibling
```

Or, actually, in case the element you have updated is already the last one and `nextElementSibling` returned `undefined`

```
next ? next.previousElementSibling : bar.parentElement.lastChild
```

```js
const bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for (let i = bars.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
  const bar = bars[i];
  const next = bar.nextElementSibling;
  
  bar.outerHTML = `<h1 class="bar">${bar.innerHTML}</h1>`;
  
  const foo = new Foo(next.previousElementSibling || next.parentElement.lastChild);
  
  // ...
  
  foo.doFoo();
}

function Foo (bar) {
  this.bar = bar;
  
  this.doFoo = function() {
    this.bar.innerHTML = `Foo${ this.bar.innerHTML }`;
    console.log('doFoo:', this.bar.innerHTML);
    // expected on page: "Dog" --> "FooDog", "Turtle" --> "FooTurtle". This doesn't happen.
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="bar">Dog</p>
<p>Cat</p>
<p class="bar">Turtle</p>
```